# Fragment transition animation caused ANR in api level 22

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions

I have a top tab layout, when selecting one tab, it switches fragments with a slide left/right animation.

For API level 22, the following code causes ANR: it doesn't give any error message, but commenting out the following code makes it works.

```
if (position > curSelectTab) {
        mFragments[curSelectTab].setExitTransition(inflater.inflateTransition(R.transition.slide_out_to_left));
        mFragments[position].setEnterTransition(inflater.inflateTransition(R.transition.slide_in_from_right));
    } else if (position < curSelectTab){
        mFragments[curSelectTab].setExitTransition(inflater.inflateTransition(R.transition.slide_out_to_right));
        mFragments[position].setEnterTransition(inflater.inflateTransition(R.transition.slide_in_from_left));
    }
```

This is how I switch fragments:

```
private void onTabSelected(int position) {
    //switch tab
    int curSelectTab = mSelectTab;
    SearchResultFragment fragment = mFragments[position];
    TransitionInflater inflater = TransitionInflater.from(this);
    if (fragment == null) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                mFragments[0] = SearchResultFragment.newInstance(SearchResultFragment.TYPE_ALL_NOTE, mQuery);
                break;
            case 1:
                mFragments[1] = SearchResultFragment.newInstance(SearchResultFragment.TYPE_NOTE_NAME, mQuery);
                break;
            case 2:
                mFragments[2] = SearchResultFragment.newInstance(SearchResultFragment.TYPE_NOTE_CONTENT, mQuery);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        fragment = mFragments[position];
    }

    //add Fragment
    if (!fragment.isAdded()) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fl_container, fragment).commit();
    }

    if (position > curSelectTab) {
        mFragments[curSelectTab].setExitTransition(inflater.inflateTransition(R.transition.slide_out_to_left));
        mFragments[position].setEnterTransition(inflater.inflateTransition(R.transition.slide_in_from_right));
    } else if (position < curSelectTab){
        mFragments[curSelectTab].setExitTransition(inflater.inflateTransition(R.transition.slide_out_to_right));
        mFragments[position].setEnterTransition(inflater.inflateTransition(R.transition.slide_in_from_left));
    }
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(mFragments[curSelectTab]).commit();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(mFragments[position]).commit();
    mSelectTab = position;
}
```

Here is one of my transition animation `slide_in_from_right`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <slide android:slideEdge="end" />
    <fade android:fadingMode="fade_in" android:duration="100"/>
</transitionSet>
```

The ANR only happens in API level 22, it is good in API level 23.

Anyone knows why? the transition animation is not supported in API level under 23? I thought it is supported over 21

Comment: please share the crash logs

Comment: It doesn't crash, just ANR. I couldn't find any log that is helpful.